# Swing: JComboBox removing/adding duplicates

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

My problem has to be able to add and remove items to combobox. those items can be duplicates.
I manage to add them:

```
jComboBox1.addItem(dodatek);
```

remove first:

```
 if (jComboBox1.getItemCount() > 0) {
                jComboBox1.removeItemAt(0);
```

or selected one:

```
    if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() != null) {
        jComboBox1.removeItemAt(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex());
```

Problem occurs when having all items removed, and one of them was duplicate.
In that case last item remains selected in combobox even though the list is empty! https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgYP4.jpg

It Also throws exception when trying to remove selected item:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -1
    at java.util.Vector.removeElementAt(Vector.java:562)
    at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.removeElementAt(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:152)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.removeItemAt(JComboBox.java:759)
```

This only happens when removing items among which there are duplicates

Comment: For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. You might very well solve the problem yourself by simply trying to isolate and expose the bug.

Comment: voting to close as too broad

Answer (score 2):

Selected Item and Selected index obviously don't mean the same thing. You need to check, if the selected index is != -1 before calling remove on it.

Selected item is the value selected in the box, selected index is the selected index in the list.

Comment: Alright that makes sense. Problem remains. Normally combobox should be empty when there is nothing on the list of items. But in my case where there are duplicates on the list, there is item selected and list is empty. This is what needs to be looked at. Check the imgurl link :http://imgur.com/sMf2HWg

Comment: not, wrong (feature of bug) if is there duplicates (in DefaultComboBoxModel) then is used last used index or first, closest index, have to create POJO arrays with abstract model

Comment: @mKorbel so what should i do to prevent that?

Comment: @Vedran, `so what should i do to prevent that? ` - don't add duplicates to the combo box. Before adding the item to the combo box you loop through all the items to see if it has already been added.

Comment: @camickr I do want to add them. Its what I am required to do

Comment: Then work around the issue and set the selected value to null if the selected item is -1. Did you try that? Or select the next item explicitly.